# Apache mod_deflate MIME type settings

Tags: apache-2.4, compression, mod-deflate

CPanel gives me [options](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/78Docs/Optimize+Website) about what MIME content types to compress with Apache's [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_deflate.html), as shown below.

[image]

**Are there disadvantages to having a long list of MIME types** (eg. slower server response)**?** In other words, is there any reason I shouldn't find or create a very long list of every imaginable uncompressed filetype?

Obviously, it is best not to compress filetypes that are already compressed, eg. videos, `.docx`. **Are there other considerations for what should be included or not included in this `mod_deflate` types list?**

Answer (score 2):

**Just compress text files** or you will end up wasting cpu cycles for files like images and such which won't be compressed more because they already are.

typical setup is to compress these mime types:

```
text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript
```

You may have more interesting choices or text files to compress, but for this is a good starting point.